# Prevent onbeforeunload dialog from interfering with tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to disable the dialog that spawns from onbeforeunload in the instance of Chrome spun up by Capybara. I have a very large test suite and it would be impractical to modify every visit/refresh to include code to click the ‘Leave’ confirmation.

I have tried adding `page.execute_script ‘window.onbeforeunload = undefined;’` before visits and refreshes, and while this works, it shares the problem of having to modify all my visit and refresh calls.

I also checked to see if there are any Chrome CLI options I could add to disable this functionality, but I didn’t find anything relevant. I checked here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but after searching for unload, alert, and dialog, nothing that matched seemed relevant.

I am on Chromedriver v2.33, Chrome 62, Capybara 2.5 and Selenium-webdriver 2.53.4. Will update this post with more info if needed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Capybaras `visit` and `refresh` methods always call your `execute_script` first the easiest solution would be something like

```
module BeforeUnloadDisabler
  def visit(*args)
    execute_script 'window.onbeforeunload = undefined;'
    super
  end

  def refresh(*args)
    execute_script 'window.onbeforeunload = undefined;'
    super
  end
end

::Capybara::Session.prepend(BeforeUnloadDisabler)
```

Although, if your app is registering beforeunload alerts that much you might want to reconsider your design choices -- that can be really annoying for users.